# CUPS Browsed only finds few printers, setting server directly finds all

Tags: fedora, cups

I use my own laptop at work. They have a CUPS server at `cups.example.org` which one can just use. So *if I did not have a printer at home*, one would just add this into `/etc/cups/client.conf`:

```
ServerName cups.example.org
```

When I do this, it does not lag when opening a print dialog and I can see all the printers in the institute.

Now I have a printer at home, so I want to use the institute CUPS server *additionally*. The IT wiki states to use CUPS browsed instead. So I have the following (among other default stuff) in my `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`:

```
Browsing On
BrowseOrder allow,deny
BrowseAllow all
BrowseLocalProtocols CUPS dnssd
BrowsePoll cups.example.org
BrowseProtocols CUPS
```

This somewhat works. Sometimes opening a print dialog in a PDF viewer will cause the whole application to freeze. Other times I see my personal printers and also a single of the institute printers, but not all of them, and especially not the one on my floor.

I have looked into the system log, but did not find anything interesting in particular.

What can I do to diagnose this issue?

My system is Fedora 26.